# Xpages - Get number of active sessions (Lotus Domino 8.5.2)

Tags: java, session, jsf, listener, xpages

How do I get the number of active sessions in Xpage. I'm trying to use managed beans but it just returns a weird string. Here's the simple code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  private static int totalActiveSessions;

  public static int getTotalActiveSessions(){
    return totalActiveSessions;
  }

  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions++;
    System.out.println("sessionCreated - add one session into counter");
  }

  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions--;
    System.out.println("sessionDestroyed - deduct one session from counter");
  } 
}
```

I got this from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter). But when I call `SessionCounterListener.getTotalActiveSessions()`, it only returns 0 (regardless if someone is logged in).

If you have the time, you can check out my test database [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs098ne95t4cnl1/test_java.nsf).

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: probably you call it wrong way, it seems you omitted parentheses.

Comment: What is the point to return "int | 0" in Java? It is not a JavaScript. A|false = A.

Comment: How do you injected the class in the application? Just creating this class is not enough. Creating a Web.xml in the NSF won't work, it will be ignored.

Comment: I used it as a managed bean. I then add an entry in the faces-config.xml.

Answer (score 6):

A session listener must be injected in the application to get working as desired. Otherwise the sessionCreated/sessionDestroyed methods will never be called and 0is returned always. But there are some differences between XPages and "traditional" JSF. Have a look here:

http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/66d9103768cc2fed85256c59006b5433/00a38cdf382f4893862578b80082dd15!OpenDocument

Or have a look inside the [XSP Starterkit](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XSP%20Starter%20Kit).

**EDIT:**

To add a session Listener, do the following:

1. Switch to java perspective
2. In the "Code/Java" folder, create a folder "META-INF"
3. In this META-INF folder, create a folder "services"
4. In the "services" folder create a file named "com.ibm.xsp.core.events.SessionListener"
5. In this file, add the full name of your class: package.SessionCounterListener

Now, the session listener should be activated.

Comment: the XSP StarterKit has no documentation. :(

Comment: Added a quick description to my reply above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I suppose you are using 8.5.3, because of the existence of the Java folder. Unfortunately, I'm using 8.5.2 :(. Can you help me with that. I have the code, but the problem is the services folder.

Comment: I already registered my SessionCounterListener in the faces-config.xml, so I suppose this is not the same in the "services" folder. And I tried to test print by calling a method in the SessionCounterListener and it works. It's just that it doesn't run the sessionCreated nor sessionDestroyed function.

Comment: you can not register a sessionListener in faces-config.xml. you have to register in web.xml. You have created a simple bean, nothing else. Thats why it is not working and not running the created/destroyed methods.

Comment: Can you tell me in which directory is the web.xml located? I cannot find it in Package Explorer. :(

Comment: You cannot find *web.xml*, because it is not there. It is an internal file inside the domino core. I just wanted to explain why you cannot register a session listener in a *faces-config.xml*. I will update the response with a solution for 8.5.2, but I have no time at the moment.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'll wait for your response. Thanks a lot :D.

Comment: Jairo there is a deck on the XSP Starter kit on Slideshare. Also the kit is actually a collection of samples that explain the xsp api. That documentation including JavaDoc is on IBM's developerworks and in the XPages extension library book. A META-INF in your sec folder (in webcontent/META-INF/src I presume) should work too - alternative: create services in the META-INF folder directly. One of the two should work

Comment: Hi Stephan! I would like to do the second approach, but I don't find any webcontent/META-INF/src directory and I don't understand what you mean about the "sec" folder. Can you explain it to me further? I'm really sorry. I'm just starting with this advanced XPage development thing. Your explanation would help me a lot! :D. Thanks for the comment :D

Comment: @SvenHasselbach I was able to make it work, but in 8.5.3. I tried to do the same (copying the directories, etc.) to my 8.5.2 database and it still didn't work. I was able to access a function in the Listener class, but the sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed are not being executed.

Comment: Typo. It should read src. Where do you store your Java soure files? In 852 the only save way is to create a src folder under /webcontent/web-inf and add that to the Java sources. Never put stuff in the /Local folder

Comment: You need to make sure your classes end up in the right place. The build path is essential. Wnhen you copy directories the build path is not auto adjusted. Right click om thr nsf and select properties to adjust it

Comment: @stwissel yes, I already did that. This is why I can access a sample function that just returns a string. I am able to instantiate the java class in SSJS. The problem is that the service, i think, is not being registered. That is why the sessionCreated and sessionDestoryed does not automatically run when a user access any xpage of my application (In 8.5.3, something is printed in the server console whenever a user access an xpage, that is why I know its working). Thanks again for the comment! :D

Comment: So where exactly did you put the file com.ibm.xsp.core.events.SessionListener ?  It should be either in yourdb.nsf/webcontent/META-INF/src/services (and thus get copied into yourdb.nsf/webcontent/META-INF/classes/services or you can try youdb.nsf/webcontent/META-INF/services (one of the two should work) - and then point that to your fully qualified class name

Comment: @stwissel Not pulling your leg or what, I am really thankful to you for trying to help me. I did try the last options you gave me, but I'm still not successful to execute the sessionCreated & sessionDestroyed functions automatically in Domino 8.5.2 . I know this is to much too ask for, but if you have the time, you can check my test database https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs098ne95t4cnl1/test_java.nsf (I included it also in the question). The last thing that I did here is to mimic the directories that I did in the 8.5.3 test database. Again, thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: it still shows 0 for me on 8.5.3 after trying different places to add a file named com.ibm.xsp.core.events.SessionListener having one line in it with my pckg.classname
any ideas?

Comment: @mike_x_: You have to implement IBMs *SessionListener* insted of *HttpSessionListener*