# How to "clean" serialized files from filesystem without restarting http task

Tags: xpages

We have an XPages application and we serialize all pages on disk for this specific application. We already use the gzip option but it seems the serialized files are removed from disk only when the http task is stopped or restarted.

As this application is used by many different customers from different places around the globe, we try to avoid restart the server or the http task as much as possible but the drawback is that serialized files are never deleted ans so sooner or later we face a disk space problem even if the gzip serialzed files are not that big.

A secondary issue is that the http task takes quite a long time to stop because it has to remove all the serialized files.

Is there any way to have the domino server "clean" old/unused serialized files without restarting the http task ?

Currently we implemented an OS script which cleans serialized files older than tow days which is fine, but I would prefer a solution within domino.

Thanks in advance for your answers/suggestions !

Renaud

Comment: xsp.properties param: xsp.persistence.file.maxviews
> Takes a numeric value defining the maximum number of pages to be saved when the ondisk or hybrid persistence mode is used. The default value is 16 pages.

Did you alter this parameter to some high number?

Comment: No, I didn't changed this parameter. But as far as I understood this is a per user parameter so if you have different users as we do and if I get it right this will not help.It will only ensure yo have 16 files per session, but the "old" or timed out sessions persisted files will remain on disk.

Comment: Please, add some more info: number of users and applications, something about your code (amount of SSJS/Java code, framworks used) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the httpSessionId is used to store the file(s) on disk.  You could try the following:

1. Alter the xsp.persistence.dir.xspstate to a friendlier location on (i.e. /temp/xspstate)
2. Register a SessionListener with your XPage application
3. Inside the SessionListener's sessionDestroyed method recursively search through the folders to find the one file or folder that matches the sessionId and delete

When the sessionDestoryed method is called in the listener any file locks should have been removed.  Also note, as of right now, the seesionDestroyed method is not called right after a user logs out (see my question here: [SessionListener sessionDestroyed not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910980/sessionlistener-sessiondestroyed-not-called))

hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for your answer. I tried it and here is what I found.

SessionListener sessionDestroyed method is called only when the application timeout is reached and serialized files are only cleaned up when this sessionDestroyed is called.

My main problem is most of the access to our application is done by anonymous users => No logout possible !

One other thing I found is that if you don't specify a value for xsp.application.timeout either in the application or in the global xsp.properties in the data\properties directory of the server, the sessionDestroyed method is not called !!

Comment: Another problem in my case is that we have monitoring system which access the server very often to be sure the application is up and running, so in our case the application timeout is almost never reached => serialized files are never deleted.

It would be great that when a session reaches it timeout time, the sessionDestroyed would be called. There is probably already an event triggered because the memory in the sessionScope is cleanup.

Comment: At the end of the day, it seems there is no solution for me except to clean it manually with an OS script which runs on a regular basis as we do now... Too bad but at least I have one solution and I hope something will be changed in the future. Thanks to both of you for you suggestions.

Comment: Hi Renaud, you could just execute cleanup w/ a scheduled agent instead of the OS script (check file age, check for lock).  At least then its contained in your app and has one less external dependency.