# Session / Application Listeners for XPages

Tags: xpages

I am attempting to create a Session Listener (and maybe later an application listener) for an xpage application running on 9.0.1. A google search did not present a lot of information, but did give a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177842/xpages-get-number-of-active-sessions-lotus-domino-8-5-2).

As the answer of the question says, I created a file with the name "com.ibm.xsp.core.events.SessionListener".  The sole content of this file is the full name 
**< package >.ClassName** 
of the class that implements 
**com.ibm.xsp.application.events.SessionListener**

I already find it sort of odd that the two are not of the same package, but Ill let this pass for now.

Now is the question, where do I put the file.  My classes are (for the moment) in the WebContent/WEB-INF/src folder which is added to the build path. Later, they will be a jar added to the project as a dependency. For right now, I am only concerned with getting it to work in the src folder.

I have tried to add a "folder" in WebContent/WEB-INF/src entitled "services" and to put the file there, no luck.  I tried to put the services folder into the Code/Java folder (really unnecessary since it is just copied back into the WEB-INF folder). I tried to add it in WebContent/WEB-INF/services, no luck whether that folder was added to the build path or not, and I am really unsure what to try next.

The listener code is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;


import com.ibm.xsp.application.ApplicationEx;
import com.ibm.xsp.application.events.SessionListener;

public class TestController implements SessionListener, Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void sessionCreated(ApplicationEx arg0, HttpSessionEvent arg1) {
        System.out.println("in test session creation");
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(ApplicationEx arg0, HttpSessionEvent arg1) {
        System.out.println("in test session destruction");
    }

}
```

Similarly, Id like to try to get an application listener up and running, but I have not tried that yet.

Comment: As I read the answer on the other SO question you reference to. Add in the package explorer in the Code/Java folder a new folder 'services', with in the folder a new file with the name 'com.ibm.xsp.core.events.SessionListener'. The run time is expecting this file to be pickedup. And finally in this file you only put the full qualified name of the class of the session listner, In your case <package>.TestController

Comment: I did multiple errors (now working).  the META-INF (not WEB-INF, guess I was blind) belongs in the same folder that the source code is written.  In my case, this was the WebContent/Web-INF/src folder.  The full path to that file in my case is then 'WebContent/Web-INF/src/META-INF/services'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some similarity, IMO, to how the NSF hooks into the Domino server in the *DesignerFacesServlet* implementation I like to use. In that particular case, I'm registering a *ServletFactory* (local to my NSF); this registers in the NSF's `/META-INF/services/com.ibm.xsp.adapter.servletFactory` file, which is stored in the Java source build path (generally `NSF/Code/Java` or `NSF/WEB-INF/src`, depending on which source location you're using). That file contains the fully qualified <package.ClassName> of the *ServletFactory*.

Here's a live example: https://github.com/edm00se/AnAppOfIceAndFire/blob/master/ODP/Code/Java/META-INF/services/com.ibm.xsp.adapter.servletFactory

The file's contents:

```
com.westeros.factory.ServletFactory
```

I'm sure someone with a better understanding of how the loading of NSF contents interacts with the Domino server could enlighten further.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, it needs to be in a META-INF folder - this works:

```
app1.nsf/Code/Java/META-INF/services/com.ibm.xsp.core.events.SessionListener
```

Also there's an issue tracked as SPR#RGAUA45NJA, where the SessionDestroyed methods on the SessionListener's aren't invoked. That's likely to be fixed in the next 9.0.1 FixPack (not fixed in FP5).